# Update timestamp in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wanna update just one row in my table using php . but it can't be done! idk why!
here is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['publish'])) {
       try {
        $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];
        // $name = $_POST['name'];
        // $email = $_POST['email'];
        // $body = $_POST['body'];
        $status =1;
        $sql2 = 'UPDATE cmts SET
                status=:status,

                 WHERE post_id=:id limit 1';
        $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
        $stmt2->execute(['status' => $status, 'id' => $post_id]);
        header('Location: comment.php');
       }
       catch(Exeption $e) {
           echo "error". $e->getMessage();
       }    
      }
```

and the html code :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $cmt->post_id; ?>">
            <!-- <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php //echo $cmt->name; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php //echo $cmt->email; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="body" value="<?php //echo $cmt->body; ?>"> -->
            <input type="submit"  value="Publish" name="publish">
        </form>
```

i just want to update one column(status) to 1. i add another columns to update and it did update the row but it effect TIMESTAMP column which i dont want to.
here is a pic of my table:
 [image]

**update**: thanks for the answers. it was for comma (,) after status. i removed it and every thing works as it should.

Comment: do you have something in `$cmt->post_id` in first place? then in segue in `$_POST['post_id']`?

Comment: your question is not clear  .. there is  not "another columns" .. and you have wrong comma after :status ..  updated  your question and explain better

Comment: `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" ` is vulnerable to cross side scripting attacks i advice you to remove the action attribute if you are using html 5 then the html still validates or use `action=""` instead if you are using html 4.0/4.1 or xhtml

Comment: The placeholder keys of array in $stmt2->execute(...) have to have `colon :`  to not fail.

Comment: In your SQL string, the `,` right after `:status` has to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySql, the TIMESTAMP columns usually update when you UPDATE your row. If you don´t want it to update, you need to define it this way so the TIMESTAMP gets the date and time of wthe creation of the row, but not the updates

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

You can read more about the configuration of timestamp [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html)